# best way to store error messages in Laravel (session or variable)

Tags: php, laravel, variables, session, notifications

I'm trying to find out what is the best way to store error messages (due to wrong parameters for e.g).

Assuming I'm declaring the accepted parameters in the Controller, but if any other parameter's given, I want to show a page that simply shows the error message 'that a wrong parameter's given'.
Very easy code Example:

```
if ($param == 'example') {
  // some code
} else {
  // accepting no other parameter and should return a page with an error message
  // session? variable?
}
return view('index/example');
```

1. There are Sessions I can use like:

   - normal session: `session()->put(...)`
     Problem: Data is kept if I don't delete it manually
   - flash a message to the session: `session()->flash(...)`
     Problem: It's for the next request, so when I correct the wrong parameter I have to reload two times to make the correct page load
   - session for current request: `session()->now(...);`
     Problem: ??
2. I can also use a normal variable:

   - `$error = 'message;`
     `return view('index', compact('error'));`
     Problem: Variable with error message will be kept if not deleted manually

I know that session flash messages are created for this kind of messages, but I don't really want to use it because of the problem I've shortly explained above.

I'd like to know about the (dis-)advantages of each method and also which is the best or maybe if there's a recommended one that's actually working pretty well.

Comment: [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications) maybe? Depends on what kind of error messages exactly

Comment: Not sure what you mean about reloading 2 times.  I think [flash() and reflash()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data) exist exactly to solve what you are asking about.

Comment: @Don'tPanic assuming I'm using `flash()` to show the error message and I type in a wrong parameter, then the message is displayed. But when I then typed in a correct parameter i had to reload two times in order to display the correct page. This situation occurred not too long ago.

Comment: but this question is generally, not for a specific event, it was just an example of a problem that happened (at least for me)

Comment: By `parameter` I guess you mean a field in a form on your page?  So I guess you hit submit, and your validation failed, and Laravel flashed the errors to the session, you redirect back to the form, and errors are displayed?  Is that right?  This is all standard ... Next you correct the field input, and ... reload? I don't understand. As I said, these methods are **exactly** built to help with this kind of problem, maybe the problem is in how you're using them?

Comment: @Don'tPanic by parameter I mean a parameter in the url. And I've  somehow solved my specific problem by using `session()->now()` instead of `session()->flash()`.

Comment: I see, and now I see you edited your question to describe that, I missed that update.  OK, yes, that's not the right case for using `flash`.  I'd simply return errors as variables in that case, since you're already returning a view (not a redirect).

Comment: @Don'tPanic assuming I'd do it like this (edited question) and returning the view at the end of the method, what would be your preferred way? Still using a variable? Would you redirect it the `if` or just wait for the return view to happen?

Comment: I'd still go with a variable. Sessions/flash are intended for carrying data *across* requests, ie over a redirect, or from one step of a multi-step process to the next.  If you're not doing that, there's no point, for the reasons you describe - you just have to clean it up anyway. If you're only making 1 request, just use a variable.  Maybe set it to `false` in the good outcome, and your error msg in the bad. Your view can check it and display or not. `Would you redirect` - unless there is some special reason, no, just return your view (even a different view).

Answer (score 5):

I recommend this piece of code that I'm using for a project:

```
/*
 * Add an error to Laravel session $errors
 * @author Pavel Lint
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $error_msg
 */
function add_error($error_msg, $key = 'default') {
    $errors = Session::get('errors', new ViewErrorBag);

    if (! $errors instanceof ViewErrorBag) {
        $errors = new ViewErrorBag;
    }

    $bag = $errors->getBags()['default'] ?? new MessageBag;
    $bag->add($key, $error_msg);

    Session::flash(
        'errors', $errors->put('default', $bag)
    );
}
```

This lets you store errors in the same place where Laravel itself does. You get the benefit of `$errors` variable being available in all your blade templates automatically. Then somewhere in your blade this standard piece of code would show the errors:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        There were some errors with your request.
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what's the advantage across from using a normal session?

Comment: This is using the "normal" session, it flashes data to it via Session::flash. Normally errors are flashed so that they go away on the next page request, you don't want the error to follow the user on each page. This function has the benefit of reusing the same storage as Laravel uses, so you can use single code-piece to display framework errors and your own errors.

Comment: flashing works the opposite way. It saves data for this request, when you make a new one - it's gone.

Comment: @lagbox When you flash something to the session, it is available right away. It's easy to test, try Session::flash(...) and then var_dump(Session::all())

Comment: I think you are reading it wrong. The data is deleted after the next request, yes. But it is available right after you set it. Try this code:  \Session::flash('testkey', 'testvalue'); var_dump(\Session::get('testkey')); You will see that the value is available right away.

Comment: you are right, i will remove the comments ... 'only be available during the subsequent HTTP request' is incorrect in the docs

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/5585  PR for the session flash docs to adjust wording

Comment: @lagbox nice :) So yeah, to summarize, I recommend using this function or Session::flash(..) for errors.

Comment: or `Session::now` since they need the variable this request and dont for the subsequent request

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to store my validation errors even when proper error response is being sent to users. I manage to solve this even in **production** as by checking exception class in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` class as

```php
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Throwable  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        Log::debug($exception->errors(), $exception->getTrace());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

> Note: I am using telescope to observe the log as settings:

```php
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // Telescope::night();

    $this->hideSensitiveRequestDetails();

    Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
            return true;
        }

        return $entry->isReportableException() ||
            $entry->isFailedRequest() ||
            $entry->isFailedJob() ||
            $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
            $entry->type === EntryType::LOG ||
            $entry->type === EntryType::JOB ||
            $entry->type === EntryType::MAIL ||
            $entry->type === EntryType::QUERY ||
            $entry->hasMonitoredTag();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request()->session()->flash('default', 
    request()->session()->get('default', new ViewErrorBag)->put('errors', 
        new MessageBag(['Error message.'])
    )
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.